# How To Write JSON Response Into Property List Using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, json, property-list

I have create `JSON` data store into `propertylist`, Its was worked very well. Today below code is not working data everything coming from `JSON` but the problem is data not storing anything, showing null values.

My Code :

```
NSArray *paths_watch = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = paths_watch.firstObject;
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newplist.plist"];
NSError *writeError = nil;
NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};

//Here I am not getting data below line           
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];

NSLog(@"DATA FOR PLIST : %@",plistData);

if(plistData) {
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
} else {
NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
}
```

Facing below Error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3851 "Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFNull')" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Property list invalid for format: 100 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFNull')}
```

Comment: What is not working exactly now? Is `plistData` `nil`? `writeError` `nil`?The `writeToFile:atomically:` fails? (there is a return to this method).

Comment: yes everything null only2016-02-24 16:31:04.439 anfan[7914:176239] DATA FOR PLIST : (null)
2016-02-24 16:31:04.439 anfan[7914:176239] Error in saveData: (null)

Comment: Is `error` equals to `writeError`?

Comment: yes. I think the line not working NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
\

Comment: error variable is undefined, did you mean writeError ?

Comment: yes. anything plm by that @PulkitSharma

Comment: The error message says  that the JSON contains `<Null>` values which cannot be saved into a property list.

Comment: NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&errors]; The line is not fetching my data but data comming only!@vadian

Comment: Once again, according the error message the incoming JSON string contains `<null>` values, the `<null>` type is not property list compliant and the serialization fails. `<null>` is not equal to `nil`.

Comment: Sorry I cant get u waht ur trying to say?@vadian

Comment: Print out your `finalDict` object and look for `<null>` or `NSNull` objects. These objects cannot be saved in a property list because the type is incompatible. That's what the error reveals and why the serialization returns `nil`. You have to replace those objects with something else which is property list compliant (`NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate`) PS: leave a space character before the `@` sign to address somebody.